# Take User Back to Group When They Subscribe

Tags: organic-groups

When a user clicks on "Subscribe" on a [Organic Group](https://drupal.org/project/og) they are taken to their profile, not kept within the group they just subscribed. How can I change this so they are kept within the group page?

Comment: Hi. How does a user click subscribe? When viewing the group page? Or, are they invited to join the group and get an email? What's the workflow? Are you using Commons?

Comment: Correct: A. You go to a group and see the "Subscribe" and then B. click on it to subscribe. Since all groups are open anyone can register to any group. No, no email needed nor any other limitations imposed. No, I don't think we are using Commons, just OG. :)

Comment: Joining a group and being redirected to your user page is not the default behavior. I have og installed, and if I join a group I am taking to the group page as you would expect. Do you know if you have any rules defined that redirect to the users profile page? You can check by seeing if the Rules and Rules UI modules are installed and going to the rules admin page. Also, I'm making the assumption that you're on Drupal 7 with OG 7.x-2.x..

Comment: There are no rules for OG to take you there. However, this is a gigantic website and perhaps there was something done somewhere. I created a new rule for when "User has become a group member" but I am unsure of what to do next.